# Does Blackberry Curve 8520 support Java?

Tags: blackberry, mobile

I want to know whether Blackberry Curve 8520 is Java enabled? Also, whether this phone provides its own SDK to develop mobile applications in Java?

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

- http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/
- http://us.blackberry.com/developers/
- http://download.oracle.com/javame/index.html
- http://in.blackberry.com/devices/blackberrycurve8500/curve_specifications.jsp